# JQM form errors pop-up box

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm making a CRUD in JQM for school.  My CRUD works fine. 
I have some form fields that are required before submitting and I have `class="required"` on the labels.  So, when those are not filled out, it says these fields are required.

I want them to be displayed in a pop-up box. I have used JavaScript to achieve this, however my footer to the form keeps showing up as hyper links behind the pop-up box.

It looks rather stupid and I'm not sure how to go about making it stop. I'll try to post some code here to get some help.

Here is the hidden error link that I used to call the error page:

```
<a href="#apartmentFormErrors" id="apartmenterrorslink" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open Errors</a>
```

Here is my error page:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="apartmentFormErrors">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Missing Fields</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, here is the JavaScript I wrote to make this work:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

    var myForm = $('#apartmentForm');
    var apartmenterrorslink = $('#apartmenterrorslink');

    myForm.validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            apartmenterrorslink.click();
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            var data = myForm.serializeArray();
            storeData();
        }
    });

    //any other code needed for addItem page goes here

});
```

Here is a pic of what I'm talking about

[image: Links appear behind pop-up]

Comment: Did you post all your HTML? Because I do not see your definition of the footer :S...

Comment: footer was not need for this page, turns out i had a extra </div> tag way up on my #home page. It was throwing everything off, i noticed it when my fitter nag was not working either.